# Combine two sets conditionally

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Person object which has a name attribute and some other attributes. I have two HashSet with Person objects. Note that name is not an unique attribute meaning that two Persons with same name can have different height so using HashSet does not guarantee that two Persons with same name are not in the same set.

I need to add one set to another so there are no Persons in the result with the same name. So something like this:

```
public void combine(HashSet<Person> set1, HashSet<Person> set2){
    for (String item2 : set2) {
        boolean exists = false;
        for (String item1 : set1) {
            if(item2.name.equals(item1.name)){
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        if(!exists){
            set1.add(item2);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this in java8?

Comment: Maybe using a `Map<String, Person>` with the name as key would help. At least it would speed up the lookup process.

Comment: for someone calling this API, it will not make sense. if you reverse `set1` and `set2` - the result will be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set1.addAll(set2.stream().filter(e -> set1.stream()
                    .noneMatch(p -> p.getName().equals(e.getName())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: One disadvantage of this approach, though, is that this requires to repeat the search of items in `set1`. The filter goes over  `set1` items per every `set2` item. Probably negligible depending on the size of the sets, but still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

If it makes sense for you to override `equals` and `hashCode` you can use something like this:

```
Set<Parent> result = Stream.concat(set1.stream(), set2.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Without the Java 8 streams you can easily just do this:

```
Set<Parent> result = new HashSet<>();
result.addAll(set1);
result.addAll(set2);
```

But remember this solution is only feasible when it makes sense to have `equals` and `hashCode` overridden.
 `

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashMap` with name as key, then you avoid the `O(n²)` runtime complexity of your method. If you need HashSet, then there is no faster way. Even if you use Java 8 Streams. They add just more overhead.

```
public Map<String, Person> combine(Set<Person> set1, Set<Person> set2) {
        Map<String, Person> persons = new HashMap<>();
        set1.forEach(pers -> persons.computeIfAbsent(pers.getName(), key -> pers));
        set2.forEach(pers -> persons.computeIfAbsent(pers.getName(), key -> pers));
        return persons;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could create your own collector. Assuming that you're certain that two persons with the same name are in fact the same person:

First you can define a collector:

```
static Collector<Person, ?, Map<String, Person>> groupByName() {
        return Collector.of(
              HashMap::new, 
             (a,b) -> a.putIfAbsent(b.name, b), 
             (a,b) -> { a.putAll(b); return a;}
       );
    }
```

Then you can use it to group persons by name:

```
Stream.concat(s1.stream(), s2.stream())
              .collect(groupByName());
```

However, this would give you a `Map<String, Person>` and you just want the whole set of Persons found, right?

So, you could just do:

```
Set<Person> p = Stream.concat(s1.stream(), s2.stream())
                      .collect(collectingAndThen(groupByName(), p -> new HashSet<>(p.values())));
```